# Pandas - Write parquet and keep column as Decimal

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm trying to write a parquet file into s3 to run a Copy into Redshift/ Parquet file is being write correctly but I got an error when try to copy: `Column type: DECIMAL(10,2), Parquet schema: optional doubl`.

The error message is pretty clear but I'm not sure how to enforce a column to be `Decimal` type.

Is possible to do it? Keep column `value` as Decimal when write parquet?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import decimal as D
import numpy as np

data = [
    {
        "name": "ted",
        "timestamp": datetime.now().isoformat(),
        "actual_data": "2019-06-28 00:00:00",
        "age": 34,
        "value": 0.10
    },
    {
        "name": "barney",
        "timestamp": datetime.now().isoformat(),
        "actual_data": "2019-06-28 10:00:00",
        "age": 35,        
    }
]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,)
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(int)
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(0)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(np.float, 2)

# df_merged["id"] = df_merged["id"].astype(int)

print(df)

df.to_parquet(f"s3://awesome-parquet-test/data.parquet", index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

To write the column as decimal values to Parquet, they need to be decimal to start with.

The values in your dataframe (simplified a bit here for the example) are floats, so they are written as floats:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0.1, 0.0]})
>>> df
   value
0    0.1
1    0.0
>>> df['value'].dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> df.to_parquet("test_data.parquet", index=False)
>>> pq.read_metadata("test_data.parquet").schema
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x7f07248334a8>
value: DOUBLE
```

But when we first convert the floats do decimals in Python, we can actually write decimals to Parquet:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> df['value_decimal'] = df['value'].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)
>>> df['value_decimal'].values
array([Decimal('0.1'), Decimal('0.0')], dtype=object)

>>> df.to_parquet("test_data.parquet", index=False)
>>> pq.read_metadata("test_data.parquet").schema
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x7f073ae52898>
value: DOUBLE
value_decimal: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY DECIMAL
```

For the conversion to decimals in Python: the reason that I first convert to strings is because otherwise the decimal would use the full precision of the floating point (resulting in more than 10 decimals)

Comment: In the line `df['value_decimal'] = df['value'].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)` how to specify precision like Decimal(18). Thanks!

Comment: ```getcontext().prec = <precision>```

```df['value_decimal'] = df['value'].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)```

Comment: Thank you! I use this to solve other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421702/google-bigquery-schema-conflict-pyarrow-error-with-numeric-data-type-using-loa

Comment: I was not a fan of the string step so I went with `df['value_decimal'] = df['value'].map(decimal.Decimal).map(lambda x: round(x,2))` This also addresses specifying precision.