# Google BigQuery Schema conflict (pyarrow error) with Numeric data type using load_table_from_dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I got the following error when I upload numeric data (int64 or float64) from a Pandas dataframe to a *"Numeric"* Google BigQuery Data Type:

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Got bytestring of length 8 (expected 16)

I tried to change the datatype of 'tt' field from Pandas dataframe without results:

```
df_data_f['tt'] = df_data_f['tt'].astype('float64')
```

and

```
df_data_f['tt'] = df_data_f['tt'].astype('int64')
```

Using the schema:

```
 job_config.schema = [
                    ...             
                    bigquery.SchemaField('tt', 'NUMERIC')
                    ...]
```

---

Reading this [google-cloud-python issues report](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7370) I got:

> NUMERIC   = pyarrow.decimal128(38, 9)

Therefore the *"Numeric"* Google BigQuery Data Type uses more bytes than "float64" or "int64", and that is why pyarrow can't match the datatypes.

---

I have:

> Python 3.6.4
>
> pandas                    1.0.3
>
> pyarrow                   0.17.0
>
> google-cloud-bigquery     1.24.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure If this is the best solution, but I solved this issue changing the datatype:

```
import decimal
...
df_data_f['tt'] = df_data_f['tt'].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)
```

Comment: I guess this depends on your use-case. Did you have a specific reason to use NUMERIC type? If not, and your data was already 8 bytes, a more straightforward solution would have been directly setting the data type in BigQuery to be FLOAT64 (or INT64 if it was integers).

Comment: Hi Albert Albesa! You are right, that would be easier, but the table schema was defined months ago, and currently have a lot of data. So, the thing is append new data without change the destination table schema.

Comment: I tried using this fix but then got Got bytestring of length 4 (expected 16), so this actually reduced the bytestring length

Comment: Never mind... I tried it again and it worked this time...