# Is there a way to upload the byte type created with zlib to Google bigquery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, zlib

I want to input string data into bigquery by implied by pyhton's zlib library.

Here is an example code that uses zlib to generate data:

```
import zlib    
import pandas as pd

string = 'abs'
df = pd.DataFrame()

data = zlib.compress(bytearray(string, encoding='utf-8'), -1)
df.append({'id' : 1, 'data' : data}, ignore_index=True)
```

I've also tried both methods provided by the bigquery API, but both of them give me an error.

The schema is:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.NUMERIC),
        bigquery.SchemaField("data", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.BYTES),
    ],
    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
)
```

Examples of methods I have tried are:

```
1. bigquery API
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table, job_config=job_config
)

job.result()


2. pandas_gbq
df.to_gbq(detination_table, project_id, if_exists='append')
```

However, both give similar errors.

```
1. error 
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Got bytestring of length 8 (expected 16)


2. error
pandas_gbq.gbq.InvalidSchema: Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table.
```

Is there any way to solve this ?

I want to input python bytestring as bigquery byte data.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you converting to bytes with `zlib.compress(bytearray(string, encoding='utf-8'), -1)` instead of `string.encode()` ?

Comment: @dikesh The size of the string I have was too large, so I wanted to compress the string and encode it. Are the compression ratios of the two functions the same? If it's the same, there doesn't seem to be much of a problem no matter what you use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't coming from the insertion of your **zlib compressed data**. The error occurs on the insertion of the value of your key `id` which is dataframe value **1** to the `NUMERIC` data type in BigQuery.

The easiest solution for this is to change the datatype of your schema in BigQuery from `NUMERIC` to `INTEGER`.

However, if you really need your schema to be in `NUMERIC` datatype, you may convert the dataframe datatype of **1** on your python code using `decimal` library as derived from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421702/google-bigquery-schema-conflict-pyarrow-error-with-numeric-data-type-using-loa) before loading it to BigQuery.

You may refer to below sample code.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas

import zlib   
import decimal

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table"

string = 'abs'
df = pandas.DataFrame()

data = zlib.compress(bytearray(string, encoding='utf-8'), -1)
record = df.append({'id' : 1, 'data' : data}, ignore_index=True)

df_2 = pandas.DataFrame(record)

df_2['id'] = df_2['id'].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    df_2,
    # In the loaded table, the column order reflects the order of the
    # columns in the DataFrame.
    columns=[
        "id",
        "data",
    ],
)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
          bigquery.SchemaField("id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.NUMERIC),
          bigquery.SchemaField("data", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.BYTES),
    ],
    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.

But simply changing it to INTEGER didn't make sense.

One more thing I noticed is that in pandas_pbq , the 'id' column has to be passed as an index column.
`.set_index('id')`

Even after applying both, the byte string still doesn't seem to be input.

Comment: Have you tried my posted code wherein instead of changing it to INTEGER, I mapped the `id` column to decimal for it to be accepted by `NUMERIC` in BigQuery?

Comment: No, I simply changed the data type to string and confirmed that the above code works fine.
Still, I am assuming that byte type input is not possible.